# using ParseAdapter Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am building an android app where it READ from data Parse.com
I am using a CustomAdapter to display data like this

```
public class Dining extends Activity {

    public Button but12;


    public void init12() {

        but12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);
        but12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent toy3 = new Intent(Dining.this, Dining_select.class);
                startActivity(toy3);

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dining);
        init12();

    }
}

class CustomAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> {

    public CustomAdapter(Context context) {

        super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>(){

            public ParseQuery create() {
                ParseQuery query  = new ParseQuery("RestaurantDetail");
          /* query.whereEqualTo("Name", true);*/
                return query;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View getItemView(ParseObject object, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (v == null) {
            v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.dining, null);
        }
        super.getItemView(object, v, parent);

        ParseImageView todoImage = (ParseImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        ParseFile imageFile = object.getParseFile("Logo");
        if (imageFile != null) {
            todoImage.setParseFile(imageFile);
            todoImage.loadInBackground();
        }

        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        titleTextView.setText(object.getString("Name"));
        return v;
    }
}
```

Then i am also using another class to call the table and display

```
public class Dining1 extends Dining {

    private CustomAdapter urgentTodosAdapter;
    private ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> mainAdapter;
    private ListView dininglist;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dining1);

        mainAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, "RestaurantDetail");

        urgentTodosAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this);
        dininglist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dininglistview1);

        dininglist.setAdapter(urgentTodosAdapter);
        urgentTodosAdapter.loadObjects();
    }
}
```

problem is it does not display any information and i don't understand why.
please help

Comment: How does that load Objects method work for `urgentTodosAdapter`?

Comment: cricket_007 , go check out  www.dropbox.com/s/t7u1wbkzyyzig4h/ParseQueryAdapter.zip?dl=0

Comment: Id rather not go to Dropbox. Isn't ParseUi on Github? I looked, couldn't see that method. The tutorials just set the adapter, and claim that's it

Comment: Just go to the link. The answer is there in detail. i am not getting errors from this. Just not getting any display

Comment: cricket_007  this same code works on another app, It doesn't work on this app. i cannot see why

Comment: I was just wondering, like should you notify the adapter, or have you verified that there is actually data at that Parse Object?

Comment: cricket_007 there is data at  that Parse Object. i can make it display from another app, it displays. but when i do it on this app it wont display

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the XML layout, then

Comment: cricket_007  XML layout?? Where would you say the problem is, The Dining.XML or the Dining1.XML layout

Comment: Dining1, if that's where you are trying to display the adapter data. Dining just looks like it has some buttons, no lists

Comment: cricket_007 The ListView is how i would like the information to be displayed, The TextView is how i would the the values be, I also have an image that sits next to the TextView. So in short the data has to be an Image and Text displayed in a List format.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. `R.layout.dining` is a content view of the Dining Activity **and** the row layout of the adapter. `R.layout.dining1` is the content view of the Dining1 Activity, and seems to contain a ListView. Please [edit] your question to include both